# Problems with running ruby with Textmate[Snow Leopard]

Tags: ruby, textmate

I have just installed Textmate on my Snow Leopard and try to run ruby.

I try smth like

```
puts "test"
```

At least i receive error message

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle: dlopen(/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: (LoadError)
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper - /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx/plist.bundle
from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/ui.rb:3
from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Ruby.tmbundle/Support/RubyMate/stdin_dialog.rb:1:in `require'
from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Ruby.tmbundle/Support/RubyMate/stdin_dialog.rb:1
```

Also i have written in terminal next commands to check what is wrong with ruby

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

ruby -e 'puts ENV["_"]'
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I really can't understand what to do to run this stuff on textmate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is a problem with textmate plist.bundle not supported by your 64bit installation of osx.
try this:
http://snipplr.com/view/40934/fix-textmate-bundles-after-snow-leopard-upgrade/